# performSegueWithIdentifier and prepareForSegue

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I have a `UIViewController *vc1` with 4 buttons. Each button causes a push segue to another `UIViewController *vc2`. `vc2` is shows some information based on which button was pushed. I pass the infomation from `vc1` to `vc2` in `vc1`'s `prepareForSegue` (its just an int value). This all works fine. Now I need to make it so that the `vc2` will also be called if the iphone is both on `vc1`(`vc1` isVisible) and a `vc1` receives a `UINotification` (something happens with a bluetooth device). Here is my code:

```
-(void) eventDetected:(NSNotification *)notification{
    if(self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detected" sender:self];
    }
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    VC2 *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    [destination setValue:value];
}
```

Right now if the proper event happens `vc2` loads twice, instead of once. And I get these error messages in the output logs:

> "Nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar" &
>   "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .corrupted. & "Finishing up a navigaion transition in an
>   unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

These errors happen after I press the back button. I added `NSLog` statements which is why I know that `vc2`'s `viewDidLoad` is getting called twice every time.

I created the push segues for all 4 buttons using the storyboard. I have not labelled them. I created the event push segue through the storyboard as well and gave it the identifier `"detected"`. I hope someone on here has some idea about what I am doing wrong. Would appreciate advice. Thanks.

Here is the current code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exerciseDetected:) name:@"ExerciseDetected" object:nil];
    [[NSNotifcationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(cancelExercise:) name@"cancelExercise" object:nil];
}
-(void)exerciseDetected:(NSNotification *)notification{
    if(self.isViewLoaded && self.view.window){
        if(self == self.navigationController.topViewController){
            if(!timerRunning){
                timerRunning =YES;
                _exerciseTimer = (NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:EXERCISE_AUTOSTART_TIME target:self selector:@selector(startExercise:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
            }
        }
    }
}
-(void)cancelExercise:(id)sender{
    [_exerciseTimer invalidate];
    timerRunning = NO;
}
-(void) startExercise: (id)sender{
    timerRunning = NO;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detected" sender:self];
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     vc2 *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    [destination setSElectedExerciseIDFromMenu:_selectedExercise];
}
```

Comment: Anyone else think that his question was in real life instead of ios specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely only call performSegueWithIdentifier when self is the top view controller

```
if (self == self.navigationController.topViewController) {

    ...
}
```

If you need to be sure something is only called once you can do:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [self foo];
});
```

If you need to run something in the next run loop execution you can do:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self bar];
});
```

Comment: Am I supposed to test the notification name? I thought that is what the selector is for? If I am wrong I can change that.

Comment: I added if(self == self.navigatioinController.topViewController) nested under my other condition and this helped alot. Now vc2 only gets called once. However I am still getting the same errors, when I hit the nav bar back button. Also I am only getting them intermittently (maybe once every 5 times). What happens is that I press the back button on vc2 and the screen animates back to vc1 but then it seems as though it animates again and a back button appears.

Comment: I think I may have solved the second problem but I am not certain. My next step was to implement a delay timer. I decided to work on that and now that there is a 5 second delay it seems to be working.

Comment: Hi MichelleJS I don't know what I was thinking, yes you are correct you don't need to test the notification name. I poked around and the EADemo sample code tests that `self == self.navigationController.topViewController` so I confident that is right. The delay feels wrong for the second issue. Are you doing your own animations? Are you calling popViewControllerAnimated? Is it being called more then once?

Comment: No I am not doing my own animations. I am not calling popViewController Animated. The timer doesn't feel right to me either. I implemented it because it is another requirement for the project and I wasn't sure where to go next with this problem. I wasn't expecting it to just fix anything.

Comment: To get back to vc1 a back button automatically appears in the nav bar of vc2.

Comment: I have updated the question with my current code. I am going to mark your answer as correct because I think that was the first necessary step to fixing it. If you know why the timer is making the rest work please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Did you always have the addObserver call in viewDidAppear? My bet is that adding the timerRunning flag guarantees that you only call it once just like using dispatch_once. FYI: I would set the timer to nil after invalidating it.